# Refresh pivot table without opening in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, closedxml

I need to add a digital signature to some of our reports. However, these reports use pivot tables which only load once the document has been opened. If the document is signed before this, the pivot tables will not load. I would like to avoid rewriting the reports to not use pivot tables.

Is it possible to have the pivot tables displayed correctly without opening the workbook in excel first? I've been using ClosedXml for everything excel-related but would be open to anything except the COM interop libraries.

Comment: That's too bad...  this would be a breeze with COM.  Can I ask, what is your objection to using COM?  There are many possible reasons not to -- I just think it might be helpful to understand which of them is yours.

Comment: It's going to be running on an azure web site so we can't really install office on it. The COM libraries are also not recommended for that kind of use.